# Web design VS Website design

Tags: word-choice

Which one is more correct? "web design" or "website design"?

For a non-technical people let's say you are going to search the internet using any kind of search engine. For a design agency for your blog what words you will use - "web design" or "website design"?

I ask this because English is not my native language and I do not know how natives people are thinking and doing that.

Answer (score 3):

I am a web developer by trade. The term commonly slung around the internet world is Web Design.

Website Design is used moreso when referring to an individual website, versus a profession. One is a web designer, not a website designer.

Hope that helps,

When surfing the web you will probably yield better results looking for web design.

Answer (score 1):

Web design generally refers to the larger field of designing web services and applications, along with the website.
Website design (I don't think I have ever seen this one being used anywhere) could also mean 'the design of the website' instead of the technical website designing.
But, I would still recommend using 'web design' as the search query for looking for those agencies.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. It's a matter of style.

I work with a company called [IndiaNIC](http://www.indianic.com) and we write both - a web designing and a website designing.

So, they mean the same. I think the term 'web designing' had been coined for the sake of brevity. That is, in many campaigns, we run out of space (for example, say Pay Per Click) wherein you need to restrict the ***number of letters***. Said that, we fit 'web designing' instead of 'website designing' saving four precious letter spaces!

[Web is World Wide Web](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/web?q=web) and websites *began* with www (World Wide Web). So, **in this context**, web is website. And for almost anything on web, it has to have an address, which we call a 'website'.

For the World Wide Web, when you want to have a website, you search for *web designer* or *website designer*